# Get data related to manytomany field

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have two model, first one is Industries, second one is experts.
My models looks like this.

```py
class Industries(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Industry name")
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True, max_length=150)

class Expert(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name="Expert Name")
    industry = models.ManyToManyField(Industries, blank=True, verbose_name="Industries")
```

on the all experts page I made an industries field clickable, when user clicked any industry, My goal is show the experts which is in this industry.

My urls.py looks like this:
`path('e/country/<slug:slug>', ExpertCountryView.as_view(), name="expert_country")`

Now I am confused with my views.py how can I create my view (ExpertCountryView) to shows me experts with this industry.
example:
www.mysite.com/p/country/trade

trade is my industry.
I hope all is understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter your `Expert`s, like:

```
from app.models import Expert
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

class ExpertCountryView(ListView):
    model = Expert

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(
            industry__slug=self.kwargs['slug']
        )
```